# Get next integer on base of individual digit

Tags: algorithm

I need code or pointer for performing digit-wise addition. For example:

```
59 + 11 = 60
55 + 11 = 66
99 + 11 = 00
```

Basically, I want to ignore carry when `9 + 1`. So `9 + 1` should return `0` and not `10`, and for any other digit it should return actual sum (i.e `5 + 1 = 6`).

Comment: can you be a bit more precise about the rule?

Comment: I think he wants to rotate each digit individually through sequence [0-9].

Comment: 21+11 = 32, 22+11 = 33, 29+11 = 30, 99+11=00 .... I will be always adding with 11, and largest number can be 99.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the homework tag.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us the language. I don't want to code in Golfscript or Brainf***, and then realize you want it in Whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increment the digits individually

```
f(x) = (x/10 + 1) % 10 * 10 + (x % 10 + 1) % 10
```

(Where % is the [mod operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) - it returns the remainder after division)

Comment: Hello, ObscureRobot, not it not typo. This is what I want. f(59) = 60
f(55) = 66
f(99) = 00

Comment: @PengOne yes, but it isn't clear that the asker needs more than two digits.

Comment: so much is unclear in that question! good solution for the 2 digit case

Answer (score 1):

Use int `digits = log10(x)` to get the number of digits, then extract each digit `x`, replace with `x + 1 % 10` and then put them back together, something like this:

```
int number = N;         // STARTS AS THE ORIGINAL NUMBER
int answer = 0;         // WILL BE THE NEXT NUMBER
int power = 1;          // KEEPS TRACK OF POSITION
int digits = log10(x);  // TOTAL NUMBER OF DIGITS

for (int d=0; d<digits; ++d) {
    int x = (number + 1) % 10; // GET NEXT DIGIT, INCREMENT IT
    answer += x*power;         // ADD TO ANSWER IN CORRECT POSITION
    number = (number-x)/10;    // REMOVE DIGIT FROM NUMBER
    power *= 10;               // INCREMENT POSITION
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to extract the tens digit and ones digit seperately, add them seperately, then put them back together.

Here's an example: note that it isn't going to help you prevent the carries for the hundreds. For that you'd have to adapt the algorithm to handle it specifically, or split up the numbers by digits and add them that way.

```
int crazyAdd(int a, int b) {
    int aTens = a % 10;
    int bTens = b % 10;
    int tens = aTens + bTens;
    int ones = (a + b) % 10;
    return tens + ones;

}
```

Here's one that's more flexible

```
int crazyAdd(int a, int b) {
    int[] aDigits = extractDigits(a); // let there exist a function that
    int[] bDigits = extractDigits(b); // puts the digits into an array

    int size = aDigits.length;
    if(size < bDigits.length) size = bDigits.length;

    int digits = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        int aDigit = i >= aDigits.length ? 0 : aDigits[i];
        int bDigit = i >= bDigits.length ? 0 : bDigits[i];
        digits[i] = (aDigit + bDigit) % 10;
    }
    int result = 0;
    for(int digit : digits) {
        result = result * 10 + digit;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it would be a pain in the ass mathematically, so the easiest would be to iterate through digits and rotate them. In Ruby:

```
def rotate_digits(n)
  result = 0
  exp = 1
  while n > 0
    digit = n % 10
    n /= 10
    digit = (digit + 1) % 10
    result += exp * digit
    exp *= 10
  end
  result
end

puts rotate_digits(59)
puts rotate_digits(55)
puts rotate_digits(99)
```

This gives you a number, so the last one gives you `0`. If you really want `"00"`, it's easier to work with strings:

```
def rotate_digits_as_string(n)
  n.to_s.each_char.map { |c| ((c.to_i + 1) % 10).to_s }.join
end

puts rotate_digits_as_string(59)
puts rotate_digits_as_string(55)
puts rotate_digits_as_string(99)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only talking about two-digit numbers, you can use a rather simple form:

```
def nextNum (num):
    val = int(num)
    if num == "99":
        return "00"
    if val > 89:
        return "0" + str(val - 89)
    if val % 10 == 9:
        return str (val + 1)
    return str (val + 11)
```

Here's a little Python program showing that in action:

```
def nextNum (num):
    if num == "99":
        return "00"
    val = int(num)
    if val > 89:
        return "0%d"%(val - 89)
    if val % 10 == 9:
        return "%02d"%(val + 1)
    return "%02d"%(val + 11)

for i in range (0,100):
    s = "%02d"%(i)
    print "%s -> %s"%(s,nextNum(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to do this for *each* character in the string `input`.

We have a function which will do this one character at a time.

```
char inc(char ch)
{
    ch = (ch + 1) % '0'; // ANSI.
    return(ch);
}
```

Now we need a function that will do this to every character in the string:

```
string szinc(string input)
{
    for(i = 0; i < input.size(); i = i + 1)
    {
        input[i] = inc(input[i]);
    }

    return(input);
}
```